# strange javascript error - object disappears

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with javascript. I have a list of objects, called "lista_rectangulos", that contains objects like this one : {x:350,y:150, ancho:40, alto:30}

The problem comes when I use this function:

```
function canBeInserted(pos_x,pos_y,ancho,alto,excluded_rectangle){

        var ret = true;


        for (i = 0; i < lista_rectangulos.length; i++) 
        { 
            if (lista_rectangulos[i] === excluded_rectangle){
                continue;
            }
            if (pos_x>(lista_rectangulos[i].x) && pos_x<(lista_rectangulos[i].x+lista_rectangulos[i].ancho) && pos_y>(lista_rectangulos[i].y) && pos_y<(lista_rectangulos[i].y+lista_rectangulos[i].alto)) {
                ret = false;

            }
        }   


        return ret;
    }
```

The problem is that when I call that function, it pushes out of the list the element "excluded_rectangle" (the name of that variable doesn't mean it's supposed to be excluded from the list, only from the comparison), and that is not supposed to happen. Look:

```
 console.log(lista_rectangulos[i]);

if(canBeInserted(lista_rectangulos[i].x,lista_rectangulos[i].y,lista_rectangulos[i].alto,lista_rectangulos[i].ancho, lista_rectangulos[i]))

{
    console.log(lista_rectangulos[i]);

                      (more code...)

}
```

This is the console output:

```
Object {x: 250, y: 150, ancho: 30, alto: 30}
undefined
```

The first one shows the object, the second one shows that that object was eliminated. I don't understand why.

Comment: Is lista_rectangulos a global/window variable?

Comment: Most likely you've used the same global `i` in `canBeInserted` function. The value is changed, hence `lista_rectangulos[i]` will be `undefined` after the function call. Declare your variables with `var` to keep them in a scope.

Comment: @Teemu Wow! You are right! I don't understand why, though. "i" is not a global variable, it's only defined inside several functions. I changed the name of that variable and now the problem is gone. However, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: You're creating implicit globals, when you define variables within functions without `var`. Always use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to declare a variable, that way it'll keep its value in the scope it was declared.

Comment: @Teemu Wow, I didn't know that! THANKS a LOT!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the value for `i` changes as you have made `i` global inside your `canBeInserted` function.  So what is happening if `i === 1` when you first log the `lista_rectangulos[i]` you get an object, but after you've run your function `i == lista_rectangulos.length`.  Obviously, nothing is defined at `lista_rectangulos.length / last index of the array + 1` so you get undefined.  If you want to test this, log `i` before both of your logs and you'll see it has changed.

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks to you and to @Teemu for helping me with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
lista_rectangulos[i] === excluded_rectangle
```

That line is the problem. You cannot simply check for object equality like that in JS, unfortunately.
You'll have to write a function that checks for equality by comparing all of the object's contents.
For instance:

```
function objEqualsObj(objA, objB){
   if(  
      objA.x == objB.x &&
      objA.y == objB.y &&
      objA.ancho == objB.ancho &&
      objA.alto == objB.alto &&
   ){
      return true;
    }else{ return false; }
}
```

Unless **excluded_rectangle** is actually being passed as **lista_rectangulos[n]** when calling **canBeInserted**.

**EDIT:** *The solution ended up being about the scope of your loop counter, but I'll leave my solution for others who come across this with similar issues, since object equality is a common issue.*

Comment: I use the === operator to check if both pointers point to the same object, that is not the problem. The problem is that I was using global variables with the same name for my for-loops (variables defined without the key-word var in the for loops). The user "@Teemu" was right. But thanks for your help.

Comment: I edited my solution to reflect that. You seem to know this already, but just to clarify: had you passed canBeInserted() an object with identical properties, the === would have returned false.